# How to match two different tables in sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these two kinds of table below:

```
 Stocks Table          Order Table
-------------         -------------
| stockid   |         | orderid   |
| stockname |         | orderqty  |
| stockqty  |         | stockid   |
-------------         -------------
```

What I want to do is when `orderqty` is greater than `stockqty` I want to display a message saying that stocks are not enough, and when `orderqty` is less than `stockqty` then it is done.

The main concern here is to identify wether `orderqty` is less than or greater than `stockqty`.

Comment: Please clarify: the first part of the question seems to be easily solved by a SELECT statement with and INNER JOIN and a CASE. But what could the next step be referring to? Save "it" to a new table? What is "it"? And "new table" as in a different table or an altogether newly created table? Thanks

Comment: @JonJaussi Please see updated question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this DB Fiddle and let me know if it helps.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hgEdnyeTTuxamXna9ELL3P/2

```
CREATE TABLE t_stock (
  stockid INT,
  stockname VARCHAR(50),
  stockqty BIGINT
);
INSERT INTO t_stock (stockid, stockname, stockqty) VALUES (1, 'salmon', 150);
INSERT INTO t_stock (stockid, stockname, stockqty) VALUES (2, 'asparagus', 275);
INSERT INTO t_stock (stockid, stockname, stockqty) VALUES (3, 'lemon', 300);


CREATE TABLE t_order (
  orderid INT,
  orderqty BIGINT,
  stockid INT
);
INSERT INTO t_order (orderid, orderqty, stockid) VALUES (13, 150, 3);
INSERT INTO t_order (orderid, orderqty, stockid) VALUES (14, 275, 2);
INSERT INTO t_order (orderid, orderqty, stockid) VALUES (15, 300, 1);


SELECT o.orderid
      ,o.stockid
      ,o.orderqty
      ,s.stockqty
      ,CONCAT(CASE WHEN o.orderqty > s.stockqty
                   THEN 'stocks are not enough for '
                   WHEN o.orderqty = s.stockqty
                   THEN 'stocks are just enough for '
                   ELSE 'we have plenty of stock for '
                   END, s.stockname) as stockqty_analysis
  FROM t_stock s INNER JOIN t_order o
    ON s.stockid = o.stockid;
```

Comment: @NigelRen good point. The DB Fiddle link is unlikely to outlast Stack Overflow. I improved the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT o.orderid, 
       o.orderqty,
       s.stockqty,
       'stocks are not enough' AS message 
FROM orders o
JOIN stocks s ON o.stockid = s.stockid
WHERE o.orderqty < s.stockqty
```